# Pandas: turn rows into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a csv file that looks something like this:

```
0 full_name, Andrew Dean, Milly Mayer,
1 automotive, 216 DYV, ...
...
```

I now would like to convert this into a pandas df that should look like this

```
full_name         automotive      ...
Andrew Dean       216 DYV         ...
...               ...
```

Any tips how to solve this?

Comment: Try this: `df.T`

Comment: The operation you're asking about is called *transposition*, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), which is a shortcut for [`DataFrame.transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```py
>>> df
    full_name Andrew Dean Milly Mayer
0  automotive     216 DYV         xxx

>>> df.T                      0
full_name    automotive
Andrew Dean     216 DYV
Milly Mayer         xxx
```

---

Full code:

```py
# Transpose, reset index
df = df.T.reset_index()

# Set column names to be the values of the first row
df.columns = df.iloc[0]

# Remove the first row, reset index
df = df.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)

# Cleanup columns
df.columns.name = None
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
     full_name automotive
0  Andrew Dean    216 DYV
1  Milly Mayer        xxx
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be right, but when I try it I just get an empty data frame...trying to figure out why